# Possibility to extend the Doctrine Expr for using PostgreSQL "ILIKE"

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I use the Symfony Framework.

It is easy enough to add ILIKE to Doctrine.

https://github.com/domudall/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Dmno/DoctrineExtensions/Comparison/Postgresql/Ilike.php

But I want to use the Expr class of Doctrine. 
Is it possible to extend the Doctrine Expr class so that I can use PostgreSQL "ILIKE"?

`$andExpr->add($pivot->expr()->ilike($searchField, '?' . $i));`

Comment: The link is broken